# WolframAlpha does not give stepwise solution for a simple twodimensional integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-alpha-queries

Why does the behave this particular way:

```
    WolframAlpha["integrate integrate x times y from x=0 to 1 and from y=-1 to 1", IncludePods -> "Input", AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, 
 TimeConstraint -> {60, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

The solution is correct. Since the y-integration is symmetric by the interval and the integrant is antisymmetric, the solution is zero.

Problem remains, no steps given by the WolframAlpha function.

Comment: Bivariate definite integration show-steps might not be a supported pod state.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau This is correct. Alpha only has steps for univariate integrals.

Answer (score 3):

You can split it into two steps:

```
WolframAlpha[" integrate x times y from x=0 to 1 ", IncludePods -> "Input", 
AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"}, TimeConstraint -> {60, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

and

```
WolframAlpha["integrate y/2 from y=-1 to 1", IncludePods -> "Input", 
 AppearanceElements -> {"Pods"},  TimeConstraint -> {60, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Perhaps, the final result of the first step, i.e. `y/2`, can be entered in the second step programmatically.

PS. I am aware of "So questions about WolframAlpha[] and related Mathematica functions are ok, but not questions such as this one seems to be about the workings of W|A". However, the use of W|A in Mathematica is the only known to me way to obtain step-by-step solutions in Mathematica so I posted this answer.